# Binding RadioButtons to choose one item from a collection displayed in a ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, .net-4.0

I have an `ObservableCollection` in my Model, displayed in a `ListBox` in my View. Each `ListBoxItem` displays a radio button which should allow the user to choose one of the items. A property of the ViewModel should record this choice by holding a reference to the chosen item.

How can I set up a two-way binding to do this?

An `IValueConverter` should allow me to bind `RadioButton.IsChecked` to the VM property, with the actual item in which the radio button occurs passed to the converter either as a parameter or a value in an `IMultiValueConverter`. This way I can:

1. Return `true` / `false` for `Convert()` based on comparison of the VM property and the item the radio button is associated with.
2. Return the item if `IsChecked==true` and `Binding.DoNothing` otherwise for `ConvertBack()`.

However, `ValueConverter` parameters cannot be bound to because they aren’t dependency properties (so I can't bind to the item to use as a `ValueConverter` parameter) and I cannot use the MultiConverter because although `Convert()` will receive both values of interest, `ConvertBack()` will only receive the value of `IsChecked`.

**Notes**

1. The built in ListBox selection mechanism is already in use for other purposes.
2. The collection of interest is nested in another collection and presented in a containing ListBox.
3. The ListBox is bound to a collection in the Model. I am hoping not to implement events in the Model collections that tell the VM how to record events in the View, for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this:

1. Include a converter on the resources node of the `ItemsPanel` which wraps each `ListBoxItem` (or somewhere else within the repeated part of the tree), so there is one converter instance per item.
2. Add a property (`Host` in my example) to the converter for the item each converter attaches to and initialise it somehow* as each `ListBoxItem` is created.
3. Bind `IsChecked` to the `ViewModel` property you need to have populated using the converter.

*I tried the `Host` property as a DP with binding to the `DataContext` (which should be one member of the collection the `ListBox` is bound to at the point at which the converter is located), but I simply could not get this to work for my nested `ListBoxes`. I resorted to the `Initialized` event of the containing element and some code behind (which did allow `Host` to revert to an ordinary property; the DP was overkill but had been necessary for binding).

The `DataTemplate`:

```
<StackPanel Initialized="StackPanel_Initialized">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <!-- ExlcusionRadioConverter.Host is initialised in code behind -->
        <local:ExclusionRadioConverter x:Key="ExclusionRadio" />
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <RadioButton
        GroupName="Exclusion"
        IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}, Mode=FindAncestor}, Converter={StaticResource ExclusionRadio}, Path=DataContext.ExclusionCriterion}" />
    <Label Content="{Binding Description}" />
</StackPanel>
```

The `Panel` `Initialized` event (**NB** this answer originally had this code in the `Loaded` event handler, but this was causing some problems):

```
private void StackPanel_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StackPanel panel = (StackPanel)sender;
    ExclusionRadioConverter converter = (ExclusionRadioConverter)panel.FindResource("ExclusionRadio");
    converter.Host = panel.DataContext as OptionListMember;
}
```

The Converter:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(object), typeof(bool))]
public class ExclusionRadioConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public OptionListMember Host { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ReferenceEquals(value, Host);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((bool)value) ? Host : Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```